# How do I know that the finger that triggers a touchesBegan is also the same finger that triggers a gesture?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

In my case the gesture is a pan.  Sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/) has a property called [`delaysTouchesBegan`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW7). This is `YES` by default. When turned on, your view won't get `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` until the gesture recognizer transitions to the failed state. So if you leave that property as `YES` then any touch you receive in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` is guaranteed to not be part of a pending gesture.

If you turn that property off (set it to `NO`) then you may get `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`. In this case, if the gesture recognizer subsequently recognizes its gesture, you will receive `-touchesCancelled:withEvent:` for those touches. This is useful if you need to look like you're responding to the touch immediately, but allow the gesture to then override you (e.g. if the touch turns into a swipe).